# App updates from server without App Store?

Tags: android, ios, app-store, webclient

I have an idea about updating App without through AppStore:

After publishing, the app has two main functions, loader function and app content function. If I want to fix some little bug, which is only one line code sometimes, or just need to change the background of APP UI, even some logic codes. In tradition solution that is updated the APP to APP store and notify the user to update it.

Is it possible, using the loader function to download changed app content from server?

Does Apple and Android allow to do it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In addition, I wanna to make an game APP, that is always needed to updated some activities UI or text in game. Lua is popular method to handle it. Is it possible to put all necessary updated files encode in a binary file download from server to APP then decode it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in iOS app. You should submit your next version app to access the new features. If you try to download codes or any other runtime content. Your App should be rejected.

Please refer the apple-review guideline [here](http://photos.appleinsider.com/App%20Store%20Review%20Guidelines%20-%20App%20Store%20Resource%20Centerai.pdf).

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to the google play [Developer-Content-Policy:](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html)

> *An app downloaded from Google Play may not modify, replace or update its own APK binary code using any method other than Google Play's update mechanism.*

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not do it. If you want to make any change in the application, you will have to pass through store formalities to distribute the application to end client.

For iOS, you can go with enterprise distribution option, but using that you cant distribute the application outside your Organisation.

For customisable background or UI customisable, you can take help of server to receive configuration from server.